# How to add parameter in httpurlconnection android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Below code send the images to server successfully.

But what I need is have to add an parameter like image description and image date to database.

I dont know how to add parameter in HttURLconnection.

```
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);


            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile_imagepath);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                + " c:/wamp/www/echo/uploads";
                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
```

And PHPCODE:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
   $file_path = "uploads/";

   $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
       echo "success";
   } else{
       echo "fail";
   }
?>
```

The code above is working well for uploading code to server.

Have to store image description in db.

How to add parameter to above code.

And how to receive it in php server side.

Any related tutorial or documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add like this in android code below  conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
conn.setRequestProperty("image_description ", imageName);
conn.setRequestProperty("image_date ", imageDate);

and in your php file add a tag similarly

Comment: Try this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm

Comment: In android side I added this code. conn.setRequestProperty("image_description ", imageName); conn.setRequestProperty("image_date ", imageDate);  And in Php side how to get this parameter values.  $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']); this code is to get the image details. How to get parameter values _Post['image_description'] and _Post['image_date'] is this correct? I have confuse in setRequestProperty("id","value"); I to set this for multipart and text in single request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686806/httpurlconnection-to-send-image-audio-and-video-files-with-parameter-may-stri)

Android code:

String parameter= "value";

```
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"parameter\"" + lineEnd); 
        //dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        //dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + parameter.length() + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(parameter); // mobile_no is String variable
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

Php code:

```
$parameter =$_POST['parameter'];
```

Comment: is it necessary to add "dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);" between "Content Disposition" and "parameter" lines?