# How to add multipart boundary using setRequestProperty in Java?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, multipart

I saw here [How to add parameter in httpurlconnection android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608433/how-to-add-parameter-in-httpurlconnection-android)
the following :

```
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
```

I didn't find at any place if I can split it and add the boundary by using `setRequestProperty` :

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","boundary=" + boundary);
```

It didn't work, can you please advise?

Thanks!